# jQuery: Select all 'select' elements with certain val()

Tags: jquery-selectors

Does anyone know of an easy way, using jQuery, to select all `<select>` elements whose val() attribute yields a certain value?

I'm trying to do some validation logic and would like to just select all those elements with a single selector, then apply a warning class to each of their parents. This I know how to do once I select all the elements, but I didn't see a selector that handles this case.

Am I going to have to select all of the `<select>` elements into a selector, then iterate through them and check each of their values? I was hoping there would be a simpler way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Why doesn't `select[value=x]` work? Well firstly because `<select>` doesn't actually have a `value` attribute. There is not a single value of a select box: there may be no selected options (there shouldn't normally be, but there can be in at least IE), and, in a `<select multiple>`, there can be any number of selected options.

Even `input[value=x]` doesn't work, even though `<input>` *does* have a `value` attribute. Well, it does work, it just doesn't do what you think. It fetches the value of the `value="..."` attribute in the HTML, *not* the current value you have entered into the form. The `value="..."` attribute actually corresponds to the `defaultValue` property and not `value`.

Similarly, `option[value=x][selected]` doesn't work because it is checking the `<option selected>` attribute from the HTML source (`selected` attribute -> `defaultSelected` property) and *not* the current selectedness of the option (`selected` *property* not attribute) - which might have changed since the page was loaded.

Except in IE, which gets the `value`, `selected` etc form attributes wrong.

Except (again): Tesserex's example may *seem* to work, and the reason for that is that that it's using a non-standard jQuery-specific selector, `:has`. This causes the native `querySelectorAll` methods of modern browsers to fail, and consequently jQuery falls back to its own (native JavaScript, *slow*) selector engine instead. This selector engine has a bug where it confuses properties for attributes, allowing `[value=x]` to do what you expected, and not fail like it should! (Update: this is probably no longer the case in newer jQuery versions.)

Summary: form field state checking and selectors don't mix. Apart from these issues, you also have to worry about escaping issues - for example, what if the value you want to test against contains quotes or square brackets?

So instead, yes, you should check it manually. For example using a filter:

```
$('select').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val()==='the target value';
}).parent().addClass('warning');
```

(There is a `value` *property* in HTML5 and supported by modern browsers, that when you read it gives you the value of the first selected `<option>`. jQuery's `val()` is safe to use here because it provides the same method of getting the first selected option even on browsers that don't support this.)

Comment: Wow, so my answer works because of a bug in the interpretation of "value"? Interesting.

Comment: Not really interesting... more, infuriatingly confusing IMO! This area of the DOM is rife with misunderstandings and bugs, in both browsers and apps, which can make it really hard to work out what's going on.

Comment: So that means that this probably shouldn't work: `$("p").not(".hidden_control").find('option:selected[value=""]')` for the same reason Tesserex' code shouldn't? The alternative seems far less elegant which is a shame...

Comment: @Danny: actually I think that should work (at least in modern jQueries - updated answer text as jQuery's handling of attributes vs properties has changed). `:selected` is defined (by jQuery - it's not a standard CSS pseudo-class) as operating based on the current selectedness, not the attribute value (as `[selected]` would).

Answer (score 11):

The existing answers don't work on select tags, but I found something that does. Ask for a select that has a selected option.

```
$("select:has(option[value=blah]:selected)")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) Is what you're looking for I believe.

Something like `$+('element[attribute="value"]')`

See also:

- `*=` [anywhere](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- `^=` [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- `$=` [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)
- `~=` [contains word](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)
- etc.

Comment: That syntax unfortunately doesn't work with select tags. But it does with other input elements.

Comment: @Tesserex: You're correct. I wasn't going for explicit mention as much as syntax. I've changed it to be a little more vague, thank you.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't necessarily work for _any_ input elements. That is, `.val()` returns the current value of a _property_, not the original value of an _attribute_, which is what `[attribute='value']` is testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
$("select[value=X]");
```

where X is the value against which you want to check the select's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a change event that puts the value in a custom attribute on the select element whenever the value changes.  You can then use a simple selector to find all of the select elements that have that value.  For example:

```
$("select").on("change", function (e) {
    var $select = $(e.currentTarget);
    $select.attr("select-value", $select.val());
});
```

And then you can do this:

```
var $matches = $("select[select-value='" + searchVal + "']");
```

$matches will have all of your matching selects.

This is a lot easier than having to iterate through elements.  Remember to set select-value to the initial value when rendering the page so you don't need to trigger a change event for each select so the select-value is set.